# Create a submenu iOS

Tags: ios, ipad, submenu

I want to create a submenu that will appear right next to the first menu and that will contain more options. The first menu is hidden and only appears when a button its clicked on the navigation bar, i used the [SWRevealViewController](https://github.com/John-Lluch/SWRevealViewController) from github for the first menu, but i can't make the second one appear . Can somone help ?
Thanks for any help in advance

Comment: can u add screen shot which type u need

Comment: I can help you: I think you should start to implement the menu you want to have. or I can even encourage to do such thing: go for it! :)

Comment: the first menu was done already now i need the second one, i made a sketch to show how it want to looks like it: http://gyazo.com/84d2b98933a4fea2419a04540512dbb1 so its like this: navigation bar on top with the button, the white area which is the main view occupies all the screen, the red only appears when i click the button, and the green(menu) thats what i need to appear too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you add another `SWRevealController` as front view controller of the root `SWRevealController`.

```
UIViewController *secondRearVC = // your second level menu controller
UIViewController *secondVC = // your second level front view controller

SWRevealViewController *childRevealController =
            [[SWRevealViewController alloc] initWithRearViewController:secondRearVC frontViewController:secondVC];

[rootRevealController setFrontViewController:childRevealController animated:YES];
```

You can find example of what I've suggested [here](https://github.com/John-Lluch/SWRevealViewController/tree/master/RevealControllerExample3).

Other option is using other side menu controller, [JASidePanels](https://github.com/gotosleep/JASidePanels), if I'm not wrong it does what you want. Anyway you'll end up using some UIViewController containers recursively, so it's just a matter of choice.

Comment: its not quite what im trying to do

Answer (score 0):

For this effect i have created a separate view say reveal view with UITableView init, at first i am giving zero width and full height for that view. If the navigation button is pressed , i am moving the main view to right like about 100px and change the width of the reveal view to 100px, place that code in animation block.

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
        //Move frame or transform view
        revealView.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,1,screenHeight);
        mainView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, screenHeight);
    }];
```